# Android GUI crawler

Tags: android, user-interface, web-crawler

Anyone knows a good tool for crawling the GUI of an android app? I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-crawler/source/checkout) but couldn't figure out how to run it...

Comment: Tried Robotium?  You can get an ArrayList of Views in an activity and iterate through them.

Comment: Hi,
@DevOfZot I'm new to android can you help me out to start from somewhere for using Robotium like a sample code or something.

Comment: Can you please specify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Getting started with Robotium: https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: @dtmilano I want to have a tree structure from the GUI.

Comment: Have you check AndroidViewclient/culebra as one of the answers suggests?

Comment: @dtmilano Actually I have posted a question on your github(https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/issues/34) and moreover as I said I want to have a GUI tree of the whole application, Can you help me more about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I don't think it would be too hard to make a simple GUI crawler using [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) and [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki).

Also, you may want to look into [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html) and [UI Testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)

Good is a relative term.  I have not used Robotium, but it is mentioned in these circles a lot.

EDIT - Added example based on comment request.

Using MonkeyRunner and AndroidViewClient you can make a heirarchy of views.  I think AndroidViewClient has a built-in mechanism to do this, but I wrote my own.  This code tries to produce a layout similar to that used by the Linux tree command.  The `space` and `line` variables are used to setup the "prefix" prepended on each line.  Of course, this code uses a depth-first, recursive traversal.

```
def printViewListDepth(view, depth=0):
    space = '|' * int(not depth == 0) 
    space += (' ' * 2 * (depth-1)) + '|' * int(not depth-1 <= 0)
    line  = '_' * int(not depth == 0) * 2
    text = view.getText()
    text = text[:10] + int(len(text) > 10) * '...'
    print " [*] %s%s%s %s %s" % (
        space, line, view.getUniqueId(), 
        view.getClass().replace('android.widget.', ''), text)
    for ch in view.children:
        printViewListDepth(ch, depth+1)
```

You call `printViewListDepth` as follows, using a `ViewClient` returned by AndroidViewClient:

```
printViewListDepth(viewClient.root)
```

Note that in the above implementation, the class of `View` is truncated, by removing "android.widget." and the the text of a `View` is truncated at 10 characters.  You can change these to suit your needs.

**Edit** Crawling the GUI

With AndroidViewClient you can query whether a View is clickable, `someView.isClickable()`. If it is clickable, you can invoke a touch event on it, `someView.touch()`.  Assuming most button clicks open a different Activity, you will need to come up with a mechanism of getting *back* to where you came from to do the recursion.

I imagine that it can be done with some effort, but you may want to start with something as simple as invoking a BACK button press, `device.press('KEYCODE_BACK', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)`.  You will probably need to handle application-specific special cases as they arise, but this should get you off to a decent start.

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, but not at the moment. Will update answer with code example tomorrow.

Comment: yeah I guess your answer is exactly what I want but the thing is that I have no idea how should I run these scripts and how should I use the monkeyrunner and androidViewClient, I read some tutorials but couldn't figureout till now, do you have any idea what should I do?

Comment: great example and finally I ran it:) but here is my question you sample just show the current tree structure of the GUI right? I thought if I set the depth variable to lets say 1, it will go one layer deep in every clickable action and print me the GUI. Can you explain the depth variable more?

Comment: The depth variable only controls the indentation of the printed text.  This code example does not crawl through the clickable items

Comment: So do you have any idea how can I do that? I mean how can I Crawl the clickable items?:)

Comment: @Ehsan I updated my answer with a few details on how I think you could go about this.  If you are satisfied with my answer, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I accepted your answer since it is really good:) and thanks for the good points and do you have any idea where can I read about the properties of ViewClient

Comment: @Ehsan Thanks.  Here are some links for AndroidViewClient:  Blog: http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/ Wiki: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki Source: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Testdroid App Crawler](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYvhyjf7HoY)
This is available in Testdroid Cloud as project type and you can easily run it on 15 free devices.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Do you have any link that I can use for running?

Comment: do you have any idea whether I can get the GUI tree of an application by Testdroid or not?

Comment: You can't, there are android tools for that - hierarchy viewer or hierarchy dumper within UIAutomator