# Android: measuring similarity between two activity pages

Tags: android, similarity, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I'm using monkeyrunner and androidviewclient to crawl the GUI of some android apps (i.e., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348376/android-gui-crawler)). BTW, it is working great! The thing is that sometimes when you click on a clickable component it will open up the same page that you are in or you have been in this it before. For example, you're in the home directory of your app and you click the home link or the app logo then you go to the same page (i.e., home directory of the app again!). I want to avoid these kind of cases. In other words, this can cause of an infinite loop of clicking. Is there any idea or heuristics for measuring the similarity between two activity pages. Or I should ask, what metrics are good for measuring the similarity between two pages, num of elements, text or etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have dumped the tree you can save it and then use some *distance* calculation against the new dump.
For example:

```
# dump the tree
tree1 = vc.dump()
# do something, here, like touch to navigate
someView.touch()
# dump again
tree2 = vc.dump()
# calculate the distance
d = distance(tree1, tree2)
```

Obviously, the trick is in how to select the distance method. You can convert the trees to strings and then calculate the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) if they are the same length, or [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) if they are not.

I have been using this method on some projects. The only thing you should consider to apply the later is the size of the strings, as the matrices become very big.
Future versions of **AndroidViewClient** will include some of these facilities.

Alternatively, you can do some visual comparison as described [here](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2011/04/monkeyrunner-visual-image-comparison.html).

Comment: Hi,
when I print the tree1 I get this:
[<com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.View instance at 0x1f>, <com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.View instance at 0x20>, <com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.View instance at 0x21>, <com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.TextView instance at 0x22>, <com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.View instance at 0x23>, <com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.TextView instance at 0x24>]
so if I want to compare two trees just based on the name of the component is it ok? I guess I also need the content of them!

Comment: Yes, you should go one step deeper and convert not just the list to string but also its components. **Hint**: `View.__tinyStr__()` may be of help

Comment: so I should use the __tinyStr__() on the tree or the view? because when I use it one the view it says AttributeError: ViewClient instance has no attribute '__tinyStr__'

Comment: [__tinyStr__](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py#L869) is a View method, you should use it on Views

Answer (score 0):

XMLUnit might be what you're looking for, http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I guess your link is pretty good, I guess I can change my views to xml format and do a comparison between the XMLs but here I'm more specifically curious about android activity pages. and their format

Comment: Aren't you using XML layout files in your IDE? I assumed you had been and could compare the current activity's XML layout with the newly opened one.

Comment: Alternatively, what click controls do you have available to you in MonkeyRunner/Android View Client? Is there no way to programmaticly specify "in this view, click everything except these specific buttons"?

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the problem, I know android activities do have XMLs, but I use monkeyrunner/android view client so I'm crawling the application which is running and don't have any access to those XML files. Moreover, yeah you can tell monkeyrunner to click except these specific buttons or links but my problem exactly is that which buttons and clicks shouldn't be clicked that's where the similarity comparison comes in.